# Laravel 5 eloquent include the row of the other table from the foreign key of the 2nd joined table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 3 sample models

1. **customer**

   id
2. **order**

   id

   customer_id

   deliver_address_id
3. **customer_address**

   id 
    customer_id

   street

   country

A customer can save many addresses on his profile but he can only choose one address per order.

I would like to get all customer orders including the address in one query using laravel 5 eloquent. I'm new in laravel so having difficulty to query complex relationship tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer extends Model {

    $table = 'customers';

    function addresses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Address::class, 'customer_id');
    }

    function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'customer_id');
    }

}

class Order extends Model {

    $table = 'orders';

    function address(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Address::class, 'address_id');
    }

    function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}

class Address extends Model{

    $table = 'customer_addresses';

    function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
    }

}


TABLES : 
1 customers

        id

2 orders

        id

        customer_id

        address_id

3 customer_addresses

        id

        customer_id

        street

        country
```

Comment: But how to construct this in a single query using laravel eloquent? using eloquent relationship methods.. I want to get all the customer orders including the address(treet & country) ..  thanks

Comment: $cutomer->orders()->with('address')->get()